# net 6.0 application: Serilog exception on startup when trying to log to Azure Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights, serilog

I've trying to log with Serilog to console and Azure application insights from a dotnet 6.0 console application.  I'm loading the config from an appsettings.json file.

However, on startup, i get the exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Serilog.Settings.Configuration.dll: 'Type Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights was not found.'
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.StringArgumentValue.ConvertTo(Type toType, ResolutionContext resolutionContext)
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.<>c__DisplayClass21_2.<CallConfigurationMethods>b__3(<>f__AnonymousType9`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier0)
   at System.Linq.Utilities.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`3.<CombineSelectors>b__0(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectListPartitionIterator`2.ToList()
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.CallConfigurationMethods(ILookup`2 methods, IList`1 configurationMethods, Object receiver)
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.Configure(LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration)
   at Serilog.Configuration.LoggerSettingsConfiguration.Settings(ILoggerSettings settings)
```

I've picked the code up from various examples on the Serilog website and elsewhere.  Can anyone see what the problem is with my code?

I have a sample program here that builds and demo's the problem being encountered:

https://github.com/ossentoo/testlogger

Program.cs

```c#
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;

IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
ILogger<Program> _logger;


Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

var config = InitConfiguration();

IConfiguration InitConfiguration()
{
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();
    
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateLogger();

    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddSerilog())
            .AddTransient<Program>();

    services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options => options.MinLevel = LogLevel.Debug);

    _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    _logger = _serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
    _logger.LogInformation("Logger initialized!");

    var loggerFactory = _serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
    _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
    return configuration;
}
```

appsettings.json

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ossentoo/testlogger/main/appsettings.json

Please feel free to fork the code and issue a change and a pull request.

thanks

Comment: The best stack overflow answers are the ones where the answerer fixes your but with a pull request? 

Comment: how else do you suggest they fix it?  At least a pull request shows accurately what needs to change.  Else they can just post the answer here.  Either works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the appsettings.json file typename for Serilog telemetryConverter has changed from:

> Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter,
> Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights

to

> Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter,
> Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you use .net6, deinstall NuGet-Package Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights 4.0.0 and install Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights 3.1.0. At least my problem is solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).